How to bundle wheel of private library dependency in a main application wheel
I develop multiple python applications all of which are packaged using setuptools>=42 to be able to install them with pip. All of them however have some shared functionality that I extracted to a different python project (library) that also can be installed using pip. However the library can be downloaded only from a private package registry on my company's gitlab (you need to be on a vpn), the library is defined as dependency in my apps. As long as I can easily install application and its dependency (lib) when on private network and specifying --extra-index-url's, it is obiously impossible to install it for my clients (they are receiving wheels). Is there some way to 'bundle' the wheel of my library inside all my application wheels, so that the final installation is just a single pip install x.whl?
So far i only managed to do it by bundling both wheels in a zip archive and providing installation shell script that first installs library and then application, but I find this suboptimal.

A wheel cannot bundle other wheels, it can only references other packages as dependencies. Bundling wheels with an installation script is probably the best and the simplest way.

You will have to send your clients multiple wheels and use the pip option --find-link to get the dependency wheels locally.

If you are distributing an application (as opposed to libraries), then you might want to consider a zipapp-based solution such as pex or shiv.
